# clean, functional script-like error handling in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Here's a fun challenge.

I wanted to created some boilerplate that allows the clean handling of precondition failures using syntax similar to perl's `x or die("reason")` approach.

I came up with this deleter:

```
struct do_exit {
    [[noreturn]]
    void operator()(void*) const noexcept {
        std::exit(code_);
    }
    int code_;
};
```

Which we can use to manage the "deletion" of a temporary `std::unique_ptr` which is maybe pointing at `std::cerr`:

```
struct exit_stream
{
    exit_stream(int code, std::ostream& os)
    : stream_(std::addressof(os), do_exit { code })
    {}

    std::ostream& as_stream() const { return *stream_; }
    operator bool() const { return bool(*stream_); }

    template<class T>
    friend auto operator<<(const exit_stream& es, T const& t) -> exit_stream const&
    {
        es.as_stream() << t;
        return es;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<std::ostream, do_exit> stream_;
};
```

Created with the following function:

```
exit_stream die(int code = 100)
{
    return exit_stream(code, std::cerr);
}
```

Now we can write the following program:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // preconditions
    argc >= 2 or die(4) << "usage: myprog <inputfile>\n";

    auto input = std::ifstream(argv[1]);
    input or die(100) << "failed to open " << argv[1] << "\n";
}
```

This works because when the exit_stream is returned as a temporary, it must be moved (`unique_ptr` deletes the copy operator). `unique_ptr` guarantees that the moved-from pointer will be null. It also guarantees that the deleter will only be called if the `unique_ptr` is not null. Therefore, exit will only be called after all streaming operations have been executed at the call site.

However, the obvious failing is that I can't write:

```
auto input = std::ifstream(argv[1]]) or die() << "failed to open " << argv[1] << "\n";
```

Because if I did, `input` would be a bool.

Here's my question. Can you think of a way to produce the required effect, or as close to it as possible?

I really want to avoid this, for reasons of efficiency in the passing case, and for clarity and elegance:

```
auto input = (std::ifstream(argv[1]]) or die() << "failed to open " << argv[1] << "\n").get();
```

Full code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct do_exit {
    [[noreturn]]
    void operator()(void*) const noexcept {
        std::exit(code_);
    }
    int code_;
};

struct exit_stream
{
    exit_stream(int code, std::ostream& os)
    : stream_(std::addressof(os), do_exit { code })
    {}

    std::ostream& as_stream() const { return *stream_; }
    operator bool() const { return bool(*stream_); }

    template<class T>
    friend auto operator<<(const exit_stream& es, T const& t) -> exit_stream const&
    {
        es.as_stream() << t;
        return es;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<std::ostream, do_exit> stream_;
};

exit_stream die(int code = 100)
{
    return exit_stream(code, std::cerr);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // preconditions
    argc >= 2 or die(4) << "usage: myprog <inputfile>\n";

    auto input = std::ifstream(argv[1]);
    input or die(100) << "failed to open " << argv[1];
}
```

Comment: Considered overloading `||`?

Comment: @Yakk I think the problem (at least in this approach) with overloading `operator||` is that the objects must exists, because short-circuiting won't work. So the whole design gets broken. The most problematic part seems that `operator<<` will get evaluated. And it's quite hard to defer it, if possible at all.

Comment: @luk32 deferring should be easy to implement via saving `operator<<`'s arguments in a field of `exit_stream` insteaf of immediate printing.

Comment: Overloading `||` will get rid of the short circuiting behaviour.

Comment: @Simple but look out for that breaking change in c++17, after which it won't...

Comment: @RichardHodges http://stackoverflow.com/q/41227353/2491746

Comment: @Simple got it - thanks.

Comment: @Yakk I bet you could improve my attempt.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's my first attempt. I'm a little concerned about redundant construction because of the lack of short-circuiting, but the syntax is what I wanted.

Comments / improvements welcome!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>

namespace detail {
    struct tuple_emitter {
        tuple_emitter(std::ostream &os) : os(os) {}

        template<class...Refs>
        void operator()(std::tuple<Refs...> const &t) const {
            emit_impl(t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Refs)>());
        }

    private:

        template<class T>
        void emit_impl(T const &t) const {
            os << t;
        }

        // make sure we handle lazy manipulators
        void emit_impl(std::ios_base (* f)(std::ios_base &)) const
        {
            f(os);
        }

        template<class Tie, std::size_t...Is>
        void emit_impl(Tie const &refs, std::index_sequence<Is...>) const {
            using expand = int[];

            void(expand{0,
                        ((emit_impl(std::get<Is>(refs))), 0)...});
            os << std::endl;
        };


        std::ostream &os;
    };

    // a class that emits a number of references to std::cerr and then
    // exits    
    template<class...Refs>
    struct dier {
        dier(int code, std::tuple<Refs...> t) : code(code), emitter(std::cout), refs_(t) {}

        template<class...Others, class Ref>
        dier(dier<Others...> const &original, Ref const &r)
                : code(original.code), emitter(original.emitter), refs_(std::tuple_cat(original.refs_, std::tie(r))) {};

        void operator()() const {
            emitter(refs_);
            std::exit(code);
        }

        int code;
        tuple_emitter emitter;
        std::tuple<Refs&...> refs_;
    };

    template<class...Refs, class Ref>
    auto operator<<(dier<Refs...> original, Ref const &ref) {
        return dier<Refs..., const Ref &>(original, ref);
    };


    template<class T, class...Refs>
    T operator||(T &&t, dier<Refs...> death) {
        if (!t) {
            death();
        }
        return std::move(t);
    };

    template<class T, class...Refs>
    T const &operator||(T &t, dier<Refs...> death) {
        if (!t) {
            death();
        }
        return t;
    };
}

auto die(int code = 100) {
    return detail::dier<>(code, std::make_tuple());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // preconditions
    argc >= 2 or die(4) << "usage: myprog <inputfile>\n";

    auto input = std::ifstream(argv[1]) or die(5) << "failed to open " << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(10) << argv[1] << " and here is a hex number " << std::hex << 40;

}
```

Expected outputs:

With no arguments:

```
usage: myprog <inputfile>
```

With one argument "foo.txt":

```
failed to open ---foo.txt and here is a hex number 28
```

**Update after Yakk's suggestions**

got it down to this - which is much cleaner:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>

namespace notstd {

    namespace detail {
        template<class F, class T, std::size_t...Is>
        void apply_impl(F&& f, T&& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        {
            using expand = int[];
            void(expand{0,
                        ((f(std::get<Is>(t))), 0)...});
        };
    }

    template<class F, class...Ts>
    void apply(F&& f, std::tuple<Ts...> const& t)
    {
        detail::apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f), t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
    };

    struct apply_to_stream
    {
        apply_to_stream(std::ostream& os)
                : os(os)
        {}

        template<class T>
        std::ostream& operator()(T&& t) const
        {
            return os << t;
        };

        std::ostream& operator()(std::ios_base& (*f)(std::ios_base&)) const
        {
            f(os);
            return os;
        };

        std::ostream& os;
    };


}

namespace detail {

    template<class Tuple>
    struct dier {
        constexpr dier(int code, Tuple t) : code(code), refs_(std::move(t)) {}

        void operator()() const {
            notstd::apply(notstd::apply_to_stream(std::cout), refs_);
            std::cout << '\n';
            std::exit(code);
        }

        int code;
        Tuple refs_;
    };

    template<class Tie>
    constexpr auto make_dier(int code, Tie&& t) {
        return detail::dier<Tie>(code, std::forward<Tie>(t));
    }

    template<class Tuple, class Ref>
    constexpr auto operator<<(dier<Tuple> original, Ref&& ref) {
        return make_dier(original.code, std::tuple_cat(original.refs_, std::tie(ref)));
    }


    template<class T, class...Refs>
    T operator||(T &&t, dier<Refs...> death) {
        if (!t) {
            death();
        }
        return std::forward<T>(t);
    }

}

template<class Tie = std::tuple<>>
constexpr auto die(int code = 100, Tie&& t = {}) {
    return detail::make_dier(code, std::forward<Tie>(t));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // preconditions
    argc >= 2 or die(4) << "usage: myprog <inputfile>\n";

    auto input = std::ifstream(argv[1]) or die(5) << "failed to open " << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(10) << argv[1] << " and here is a hex number " << std::hex << 40;
}
```

Comment: `template<class T, class...Refs>T operator||(T &&t, dier<Refs...> death) { if (!t) { death(); } return std::forward<T>(t); };` and no need for 2 overloads.

Comment: Template dier on tuple stored, not on args.  Write factory that takes tuple and deduces dier type.  Feed it with tuple cat.  Use generic `foreach(f)(args...)` and a C++17-esque apply to stream, cut out special purpose code from emitter.

Comment: This is one of the cases where `std::endl` seems wise, before calling `exit`, flush those buffers!  ;)

Comment: @Yakk I think you're right. The documentation for `std::exit` only promises to flush C streams. It probably works anyway in libc++ and stdlibc++ but only by coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt to improve @RichardHodges self answer.

First, some library esque code:

```
namespace notstd {
  // takes a function object
  // returns a function object that calls the first function object once for each argument
  template<class F>
  auto foreach( F&& f ) {
    return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&...args)mutable{
      using discard=int[];
      (void)discard{0,(void(
        f(decltype(args)(args))
      ),0)...};
    };
  }
  // weak version of std::apply:
  template<std::size_t...Is, class F, class Tuple>
  decltype(auto) apply( std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f, Tuple&& tup) {
    return std::forward<F>(f)( std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tup))... );
  }
  template<class F, class Tuple>
  decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Tuple&& tup) {
    auto indexes = std::make_index_sequence< std::tuple_size< std::remove_reference_t<Tuple> >{} >{};
    return apply(indexes, std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(tup) );
  }
}
```

now we use it.  This code is briefer due to the above:

```
namespace death {
  namespace details {
    template<class Tuple>
    struct dier;
  }

  template<class Tuple=std::tuple<>>
  details::dier<Tuple> die( int code, std::ostream& os = std::cerr, Tuple&& tuple={} ) {
    return {code, os, std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)};
  }

  namespace details {
    // a class that emits a number of references to std::cerr and then
    // exits  
    template<class Tuple>
    struct dier {
      void operator()() const {
        notstd::apply( notstd::foreach( [&](auto const&e){ os << e; } ), refs_ );
        os << std::endl;
        std::exit(code);
      }

      int code;
      std::ostream& os;
      Tuple refs_;
      template<class Ref>
      friend auto operator<<(dier&& original, Ref const &ref) {
        return die( original.code, original.os,  std::tuple_cat( std::move(original).refs_, std::tie(ref) ) );
      }
      template<class T>
      friend T operator||(T &&t, dier&& death) {
        if (!t) {
          death();
        }
        return std::forward<T>(t);
      }
    };
  }
}

auto die(int code = 100, std::ostream& os = std::cerr) {
  return death::die(code, os);
}
```

Hope that helps.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/693093cefd72aa76).

Note that all `...` is eliminated except in the utility code.

Comment: nice suggestions - thank you. In my update I have done away with the emitter and instead created a function object called apply_to_stream (which I think has many other uses)

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes, eliminating it does clean it up.  I didn't bother with `apply_to_stream`, that is just `apply( foreach([&](auto&& e){os<<e;}, tuple )`.

Comment: Oh you're right. Why did I think I had to specialise for the unary manipulator? Nice.